# UIWebView close video clears content in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview, ios6.1

I'm using a UIWebView to show content with embedded videos (Youtube and Vimeo iFrames). The modal video player initially worked great out of the box. I updated to iOS 6.1 SDK and now when I close the video player the UIWebView has been cleared and does not re-render the content. Any suggestions on what I need to change to get this to work correctly in iOS 6.1?

Comment: Are you perhaps dropping the view on the floor when you get `-viewWill/DidDisappear:`, or when you get a memory warning?

Comment: I'm not getting a memory warning. I added a line to reset the content in viewWillAppear (which gets called after close) and that does render the content. So the view is still there and the controller has a reference. I like to not have to do that but it may be the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reseting the content in viewWillAppear (which gets called after the video closes) and that renders correctly.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.html baseURL:self.url];
}
```